# Android: App Crashes on LaunchActivity {java.lang.SecurityException}

Tags: android

Some of the Samsung J series phones & Huawei phones running Android 7.0
or higher are getting app crashes when they open my app. When I checked inside the Google Play logs I found below logs. Please someone tell me how can I solve this issue? App crashes on launch itself.

I am using Eclipse with Google Play Services & App Compat v7 Library.

Here's the logs from Google Play console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.checkMode (ContextImpl.java:2369)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:383)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:378)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbw.zzv (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbx.zzw (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzby.zzw (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzq.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzc.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzf.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.zzcT (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.zzcS (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzy.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd (Unknown Source)
  at app.test.ActivityMain.onCreate (ActivityMain.java:112)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6956)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

Comment: Post your ActivityMain.java

Comment: Android Left Support from Eclipse, move on Android Studio.
Android Studio is more than 1000X powerfull then Eclipse

Comment: here's link to source code https://pastebin.com/YQ9yuKT5

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in my APP since May 1. It looks like the problem is caused by new version of Google Play Services for this devices.

1. First off all: you should put loadAd in Try Catch section and handle
   the exception
2. Second: you can wait until Google fix its services
3. Third: your users can uninstall (deactivate) current version of
   Google Play Services and update it once again (by googling its name
   and opening it in Play Store) <- works for some people

//Edit

Issue trakcer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79405933
Third sollution works only until next reboot...

Comment: How can i  put loadAd in Try Catch section and handle the exception?
i am new to android please explain and also regarding above problem...how did u find the solution?

Answer (score -3):

Only solution i found right now is to Clear DATA All of Google Play Services but once user reboot his phone...it crash my app again & user has to Clear DATA All of Google Play Services. I want permanent solution for this.