# App Crash when loading admob for Samsung J series phones & Huawei phones running Android 7.0 or higher

Tags: android, admob

I had problem showing Admob ads which was crashing my app for Some of the Samsung J series phones & Huawei phones running Android 7.0 or higher.

Here's my question which was already asked:
[Android: App Crashes on LaunchActivity {java.lang.SecurityException}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323915/android-app-crashes-on-launchactivity-java-lang-securityexception#)

Right now what i did is put loadAd in Try Catch section and handle the exception but this makes my app adsless or no ads for those mobiles which is huge loss for me because its in high in numbers.

how can i load admob in such a way that for those devices for which it is crashing can have other ad network (ie. facebook audience network) ???

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
```

Comment: can u please explain by adding External Storage Permission... what it will do?

Comment: @janedona have you tried implementing this? We're also having same issue!